# Prevent Rickshaw/D3 from showing x axis labels above a given zoom level

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I'm new to JS/D3 and Rickshaw. I'm trying to modify the 
 [example plot](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html) 
to suit my needs.

My x axis is a sequence of DNA, i.e. a combination of the letters ACTG. I've got this sequence to be used as x axis labels by parsing it into an array and then using

```
var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X( {
    graph: graph,
    tickFormat: function(x) {
        return dna[x]
    }
} );
```

My problem is now that when zooming out of the plot, Rickshaw by default selects random letters across my sequence to display as x axis labels. This makes sense for a numeric x axis, but not in my case.

I need to change the behavior of Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X to only show x axis labels when the zoom level is high enough. I understand that I need to somehow find hte zoom level and set the axis labels to an empty string if its too low. I still don't know where to start, even after reading the very similar question 
[here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20010864/d3-axis-labels-become-too-fine-grained-when-zoomed-in).

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution: I implemented a formatter for the xaxis labels that checks the range for the xaxis and returns empty labels if it is too large.

```
var ticksTreatment = 'glow';
var pixelsPerTick = 10
xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X( {
    graph: graph,
    ticksTreatment: ticksTreatment,
    pixelsPerTick: pixelsPerTick,
    tickFormat: function(x) {
        var maxdist = 900/pixelsPerTick // width/pixelpertick
        var xvalues = graph.stackedData[0] // first line, but they all share the same x 
        var xmin = xvalues[0].x
        var xmax = xvalues[xvalues.length-1].x
        var dist = xmax-xmin

        if (dist < maxdist) {
            return dna[x]
            }
        else {return ""}

    }
} );
```