# How do I modify ticks and format labels on D3 axes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axes, brush

I'm working with [this example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/29/multiple-area-charts-with-d3-js/), but am struggling to find how to format the x axes to prevent overlap. I believe some of the difficulties I'm experiencing are due to the brush for the zoom/pan option. I'm trying to move the August labels to the right so they don't overlap the y-axis. Additionally, the brush labels completely overlap each other and I'd like to fix that as well.

[image: screenshot]
x-axis code

```
this.xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale).orient("bottom");
this.xAxisBottom = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale).orient("top");
```

brush code

```
context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("y",0)
        .attr("height", contextHeight);
```

I've tried modifying the x-axis directly by selecting an x-axis and calling `.ticks(5)`, but all it does is return a bunch of code related to the axis functions.

Please let me know if I should include more coherent explanations or examples, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this problem we have to write custom tick format functions.

Same problem occurred while zooming is solved in below link.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010864/d3-axis-labels-become-too-fine-grained-when-zoomed-in
```

Below link helps you in solving your problem directly

```
http://jsfiddle.net/BdGv5/3/
```

Three custom javascript functions helps you to change your axis format.

Comment: If the contents of these links provides the answer the OP is looking for, then you should summarize them in your answer. Simply posting links to external resources is not considered a good answer. Links dry up all the time and future viewers of this thread will have no idea what the solution is.