# is it possible to add vertical line to select current data on linechart?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, bar-chart, linechart

i want to add a vertical line when selecting and displaying informations at each point (it is difficle for me to put the mouse on the point) so i want to add a vertical line tooltip as cursor to display inforamtions at particular point
this is my code to display linechart  :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>


/******************************************
* Metric Modal Chart (Views, Downloads, Citations)
********************************************/

/* When there is no data ...*/

#metric-modal .metric-chart text {
    fill: #565656;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "sans serif";
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart text.no-data {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    fill:#d0d0d0;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.no-data {
    fill: #f5f5f5;
}

/* When there is data ...*/

/* CB: padding to display better on bl.ocks.org */
#metric-modal {
    padding: 64px;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.plot-background{
    fill: white;
}

/* complete data line */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #00AA8D; /* default, changed in each theme */
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}

/* complete data area */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area {
    fill: #00AA8D; /* CB default, changed in each theme */
    opacity: 0.6;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
}

/*missing data line */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.line_missing {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #00AA8D; /* default, changed in each theme */
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1.5px 2px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}
/*missing data area */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area_missing {
    fill: #00AA8D; /* CB default, changed in each theme */
    opacity: 0.15;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area_missing:active,
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area:active {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grabbing;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .axis {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .x.axis .domain{
    display:none;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .x.axis line {
    stroke: white;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .context .x.axis line {
    display: none;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .y.axis .domain{
    display: none;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .y.axis.title{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .y.axis line {
    stroke: #565656;
    stroke-dasharray: 2,2;
    stroke-opacity: 0.3;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .07;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.pane {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
    fill: white;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.pane:active {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grabbing;
}

/* brush handles  */
#metric-modal .metric-chart .resize .handle {
    fill: #555;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .resize .handle-mini {
    fill: white;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke: #555;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .scale_button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .scale_button rect {
    fill: #eaeaea;
}
#metric-modal .metric-chart .scale_button:hover text {
    fill: #417DD6;
    transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart text#displayDates  {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* circle style */
#metric-modal .metric-chart .dot {
    fill: white;
    stroke: #00AA8D; /* default, changed in each theme */
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
    cursor: default;
    transition: stroke-width 0.06s ease-in;
    transition: stroke 0.06s ease-in;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .dot:hover {
    stroke: #00997e;
    stroke-width: 6px;
    transition: stroke-width 0.06s ease-out;
    transition: stroke 0.06s ease-out;
}

div.tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background: white;
    color: #565656;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

}

</style>
<body>
<div id="metric-modal"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

// example data
var metricName   = "views";
var metricCount  = [1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4];
var metricMonths = ["2018-06", "2013-04", "2015-11", "2012-10", "2014-09", "2014-02", "2016-02", "2016-04", "2016-06", "2014-12", "2013-07", "2017-01", "2015-10", "2012-12", "2013-05", "2018-04", "2015-06", "2017-03", "2014-08",
                    "2017-07", "2013-02", "2012-07", "2016-03", "2017-06", "2018-07", "2014-10", "2013-01", "2013-10", "2017-11", "2014-05", "2012-11", "2015-01", "2018-03", "2015-12", "2015-08", "2016-08", "2014-11", "2014-01",
                    "2013-06", "2012-08", "2015-09", "2016-07", "2013-03", "2012-09", "2016-05"];
var optwidth        = 600;
var optheight       = 370;


/*
* ========================================================================
*  Prepare data
* ========================================================================
*/


// to find missing data: get a sequence of all months between the min and max dates in the data.

// change dates to milliseconds
metricMonths.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
  theArray[index] = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse(part).getTime();
});

// get a list of all months in the range of data
var monthArray = d3.time.scale()
                .domain(d3.extent(metricMonths))
                .ticks(d3.time.months, 1);

// check if there is data for each month in monthArray, if so append count, otherwise append null
var dataset = [];
for(var i=0; i<monthArray.length; i++){

    var n = metricMonths.indexOf(monthArray[i].getTime());
    if (n>-1) {
        var count = metricCount[n];
    } else {
        var count = null;
    }
    dataset.push({count: count, month: monthArray[i]});
}

// a dataset without the null values is also needed to draw the missing data lines/areas
var dataset_no_null = dataset.filter(function(d) { return d.count !== null; });

/*
* ========================================================================
*  sizing
* ========================================================================
*/

/* === Focus chart === */

var margin  = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 20},
    width   = optwidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height  = optheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

/* === Context chart === */

var margin_context = {top: 320, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    height_context = optheight - margin_context.top - margin_context.bottom;

/*
* ========================================================================
*  x and y coordinates
* ========================================================================
*/

// the date range of available data:
var dataXrange = d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.month; });
var dataYrange = [0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.count; })];

// maximum date range allowed to display
var mindate = dataXrange[0],  // use the range of the data
    maxdate = dataXrange[1];

var DateFormat    =  d3.time.format("%b %Y");

var dynamicDateFormat = timeFormat([
    [d3.time.format("%Y"), function() { return true; }],// <-- how to display when Jan 1 YYYY
    [d3.time.format("%b %Y"), function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
    [function(){return "";}, function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }]
]);

/* === Focus Chart === */

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, (width)])
    .domain(dataXrange);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(dataYrange);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
        .tickSize(-(height))
    .ticks(customTickFunction)
    .tickFormat(dynamicDateFormat);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(4)
    .tickSize(-(width))
    .orient("right");

/* === Context Chart === */

var x2 = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([mindate, maxdate]);

var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height_context, 0])
    .domain(y.domain());

var xAxis_context = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x2)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(customTickFunction)
    .tickFormat(dynamicDateFormat);

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Plotted line and area variables
* ========================================================================
*/

/* === Focus Chart === */

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.count !== null; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .defined(line.defined())
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y0((height))
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

var line_missing = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

var area_missing = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y0((height))
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });


/* === Context Chart === */

var line_context = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.count !== null; })
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

var area_context = d3.svg.area()
    .defined(line_context.defined())
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y0((height_context))
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

var line_context_missing = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

var area_context_missing = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y0((height_context))
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Variables for brushing and zooming behaviour
* ========================================================================
*/

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed)
    .on("brushend", brushend);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", draw)
    .on("zoomend", brushend);

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Define the SVG area ("vis") and append all the layers
* ========================================================================
*/

// === the main components === //

var vis = d3.select("#metric-modal").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "metric-chart");// CB -- "line-chart" -- CB //

vis.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    // clipPath is used to keep line and area from moving outside of plot area when user zooms/scrolls/brushes

var rect = vis.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "pane")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = vis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_context.left + "," + margin_context.top + ")");

var focus = vis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

rect.call(zoom)
    .call(draw);

// === current date range text & zoom buttons === //

var display_range_group = vis.append("g")
    .attr("id", "buttons_group")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ","+ 0 +")");

var expl_text = display_range_group.append("text")
    .text("Showing data from: ")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ","+ 10 +")");

display_range_group.append("text")
    .attr("id", "displayDates")
    .text(DateFormat(dataXrange[0]) + " - " + DateFormat(dataXrange[1]))
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 82 + ","+ 10 +")");

var expl_text = display_range_group.append("text")
    .text("Zoom to: ")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 180 + ","+ 10 +")");

// === the zooming/scaling buttons === //

var button_width = 40;
var button_height = 14;

// don't show year button if < 1 year of data
var dateRange  = dataXrange[1] - dataXrange[0],
    ms_in_year = 31540000000;

if (dateRange < ms_in_year)   {
    var button_data =["month","data"];
} else {
    var button_data =["year","month","data"];
};

var button = display_range_group.selectAll("g")
    .data(button_data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "scale_button")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (220 + i*button_width + i*10) + ",0)"; })
    .on("click", scaleDate);

button.append("rect")
    .attr("width", button_width)
    .attr("height", button_height)
    .attr("rx", 1)
    .attr("ry", 1);

button.append("text")
    .attr("dy", (button_height/2 + 3))
    .attr("dx", button_width/2)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

/* === focus chart === */

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width) + ", 0)");

// missing data area
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "area_missing")
    .attr("d", area_missing)
    .call(zoom)
    .call(draw);

// complete data area
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .call(zoom)
    .call(draw);

// x-axis
focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// missing data line
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "line_missing")
    .attr("d", line_missing);

// complete data line
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

// circles
focus.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset_no_null)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {show_tooltip(d)} )
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {hide_tooltip(d)} );

/* === tooltip === */
var div = d3.select("#metric-modal").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

/* === context chart === */

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "area_missing")
    .attr("d", area_context_missing);

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area_context);

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "line_missing")
    .attr("d", line_context_missing);

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line_context);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height_context + ")")
    .call(xAxis_context);

/* === brush (part of context chart)  === */

var brushg = context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush);

brushg.selectAll(".extent")
   .attr("y", -6)
   .attr("height", height_context + 8);
   // .extent is the actual window/rectangle showing what's in focus

brushg.selectAll(".resize")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," +  -3 + ")")
    .attr('rx', 2)
    .attr('ry', 2)
    .attr("height", height_context + 6)
    .attr("width", 3);

brushg.selectAll(".resize")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "handle-mini")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-2,8)")
    .attr('rx', 3)
    .attr('ry', 3)
    .attr("height", (height_context/2))
    .attr("width", 7);
    // .resize are the handles on either size
    // of the 'window' (each is made of a set of rectangles)

/* === y axis title === */

vis.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y axis title")
    .text("Monthly " + this.metricName)
    .attr("x", (-(height/2)))
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

// allows zooming before any brush action
zoom.x(x);

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Functions
* ========================================================================
*/

// === tick/date formatting functions ===
// from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010864/d3-axis-labels-become-too-fine-grained-when-zoomed-in

function timeFormat(formats) {
  return function(date) {
    var i = formats.length - 1, f = formats[i];
    while (!f[1](date)) f = formats[--i];
    return f[0](date);
  };
};

function customTickFunction(t0, t1, dt)  {
    var labelSize = 42; //
    var maxTotalLabels = Math.floor(width / labelSize);

    function step(date, offset)
    {
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + offset);
    }

    var time = d3.time.month.ceil(t0), times = [], monthFactors = [1,3,4,12];

    while (time < t1) times.push(new Date(+time)), step(time, 1);
    var timesCopy = times;
    var i;
    for(i=0 ; times.length > maxTotalLabels ; i++)
        times = _.filter(timesCopy, function(d){
            return (d.getMonth()) % monthFactors[i] == 0;
        });

    return times;
};

// === tooltip functions === //

// from: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369
function show_tooltip(d) {

    if (d.count == 1) {
        var metricName_point = metricName.slice(0, -1);
    } else {
        var metricName_point = metricName;
    }

    div.transition()
        .duration(60)
        .style("opacity", 0.98);
    div.html("<b>" + DateFormat(d.month) + "</b><br/>"  + d.count + " " + metricName_point)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX -30) + "px")//(d3.event.pageX) + "px"
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY -40) + "px");//(d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"
    };

function hide_tooltip(d) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(60)
                .style("opacity", 0);
};


// === brush and zoom functions ===

function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    common_behaviour();
    // Reset zoom scale's domain
    zoom.x(x);
    updateDisplayDates();
    setYdomain();

}

function draw() {
    setYdomain();
    common_behaviour();
    // Force changing brush range
    brush.extent(x.domain());
    vis.select(".brush").call(brush);
    // and update the text showing range of dates.
    updateDisplayDates();
}

function common_behaviour() {
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
    focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
    focus.select(".area_missing").attr("d", area_missing);
    focus.select(".line_missing").attr("d", line_missing);
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    focus.selectAll(".dot")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); });
};

function brushend() {
// when brush stops moving:

    // check whether chart was scrolled out of bounds and fix,
    var b = brush.extent();
    var out_of_bounds = brush.extent().some(function(e) { return e < mindate | e > maxdate; });
    if (out_of_bounds){ b = moveInBounds(b) };

};

function updateDisplayDates() {

    var b = brush.extent();
    // update the text that shows the range of displayed dates
    var localBrushDateStart = (brush.empty()) ? DateFormat(dataXrange[0]) : DateFormat(b[0]),
        localBrushDateEnd   = (brush.empty()) ? DateFormat(dataXrange[1]) : DateFormat(b[1]);

    // Update start and end dates in upper right-hand corner
    d3.select("#displayDates")
        .text(localBrushDateStart == localBrushDateEnd ? localBrushDateStart : localBrushDateStart + " - " + localBrushDateEnd);
};

function moveInBounds(b) {
// move back to boundaries if user pans outside min and max date.

    var ms_in_year = 31536000000,
        brush_start_new,
        brush_end_new;

    if       (b[0] < mindate)   { brush_start_new = mindate; }
    else if  (b[0] > maxdate)   { brush_start_new = new Date(maxdate.getTime() - ms_in_year); }
    else                        { brush_start_new = b[0]; };

    if       (b[1] > maxdate)   { brush_end_new = maxdate; }
    else if  (b[1] < mindate)   { brush_end_new = new Date(mindate.getTime() + ms_in_year); }
    else                        { brush_end_new = b[1]; };

    brush.extent([brush_start_new, brush_end_new]);

    brush(d3.select(".brush").transition());
    brushed();
    draw();

    return(brush.extent())
};

function setYdomain(){
// this function dynamically changes the y-axis to fit the data in focus

    // get the min and max date in focus
    var xleft = new Date(x.domain()[0]);
    var xright = new Date(x.domain()[1]);

    // a function that finds the nearest point to the right of a point
    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.month; }).right;

    // get the y value of the line at the left edge of view port:
    var iL = bisectDate(dataset_no_null, xleft);

    if (dataset_no_null[iL] !== undefined && dataset_no_null[iL-1] !== undefined) {

        var left_dateBefore = dataset_no_null[iL-1].month,
            left_dateAfter = dataset_no_null[iL].month;

        var intfun = d3.interpolateNumber(dataset_no_null[iL-1].count, dataset_no_null[iL].count);
        var yleft = intfun((xleft-left_dateBefore)/(left_dateAfter-left_dateBefore));
    } else {
        var yleft = 0;
    }

    // get the x value of the line at the right edge of view port:
    var iR = bisectDate(dataset_no_null, xright);

    if (dataset_no_null[iR] !== undefined && dataset_no_null[iR-1] !== undefined) {

        var right_dateBefore = dataset_no_null[iR-1].month,
            right_dateAfter = dataset_no_null[iR].month;

        var intfun = d3.interpolateNumber(dataset_no_null[iR-1].count, dataset_no_null[iR].count);
        var yright = intfun((xright-right_dateBefore)/(right_dateAfter-right_dateBefore));
    } else {
        var yright = 0;
    }

    // get the y values of all the actual data points that are in view
    var dataSubset = dataset.filter(function(d){ return d.month >= xleft && d.month <= xright; });
    var countSubset = [];
    dataSubset.map(function(d) {countSubset.push(d.count);});

    // add the edge values of the line to the array of counts in view, get the max y;
    countSubset.push(yleft);
    countSubset.push(yright);
    var ymax_new = d3.max(countSubset);

    if(ymax_new == 0){
        ymax_new = dataYrange[1];
    }

    // reset and redraw the yaxis
    y.domain([0, ymax_new*1.05]);
    focus.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

};

function scaleDate(d,i) {
// action for buttons that scale focus to certain time interval

    var b = brush.extent(),
        interval_ms,
        brush_end_new,
        brush_start_new;

    if      (d == "year")   { interval_ms = 31536000000}
    else if (d == "month")  { interval_ms = 2592000000 };

    if ( d == "year" | d == "month" )  {

        if((maxdate.getTime() - b[1].getTime()) < interval_ms){
        // if brush is too far to the right that increasing the right-hand brush boundary would make the chart go out of bounds....
            brush_start_new = new Date(maxdate.getTime() - interval_ms); // ...then decrease the left-hand brush boundary...
            brush_end_new = maxdate; //...and set the right-hand brush boundary to the maxiumum limit.
        } else {
        // otherwise, increase the right-hand brush boundary.
            brush_start_new = b[0];
            brush_end_new = new Date(b[0].getTime() + interval_ms);
        };

    } else if ( d == "data")  {
        brush_start_new = dataXrange[0];
        brush_end_new = dataXrange[1]
    } else {
        brush_start_new = b[0];
        brush_end_new = b[1];
    };

    brush.extent([brush_start_new, brush_end_new]);

    // now draw the brush to match our extent
    brush(d3.select(".brush").transition());
    // now fire the brushstart, brushmove, and brushend events
    brush.event(d3.select(".brush").transition());
};

</script>
</body>
```

i want to add a vertical line when selecting and displaying informations at each point (it is difficle for me to put the mouse on the point) so i want to add a vertical line tooltip as cursor to display inforamtions at particular point

Answer (score -1):

Add tihs code:

```
const selectLine = vis.append('line').attr('y1', top).attr('y2', bottom).style('stroke', 'line color');

vis.on('mousemove', () => selectLine.attr('x1', d3.event.layerX).attr('x2', d3.event.layerX));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>


/******************************************
* Metric Modal Chart (Views, Downloads, Citations)
********************************************/

/* When there is no data ...*/

#metric-modal .metric-chart text {
    fill: #565656;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "sans serif";
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart text.no-data {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    fill:#d0d0d0;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.no-data {
    fill: #f5f5f5;
}

/* When there is data ...*/

/* CB: padding to display better on bl.ocks.org */
#metric-modal {
    padding: 64px;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.plot-background{
    fill: white;
}

/* complete data line */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #00AA8D; /* default, changed in each theme */
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}

/* complete data area */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area {
    fill: #00AA8D; /* CB default, changed in each theme */
    opacity: 0.6;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
}

/*missing data line */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.line_missing {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #00AA8D; /* default, changed in each theme */
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1.5px 2px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}
/*missing data area */
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area_missing {
    fill: #00AA8D; /* CB default, changed in each theme */
    opacity: 0.15;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area_missing:active,
#metric-modal .metric-chart path.area:active {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grabbing;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .axis {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .x.axis .domain{
    display:none;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .x.axis line {
    stroke: white;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .context .x.axis line {
    display: none;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .y.axis .domain{
    display: none;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .y.axis.title{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .y.axis line {
    stroke: #565656;
    stroke-dasharray: 2,2;
    stroke-opacity: 0.3;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .07;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.pane {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
    fill: white;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart rect.pane:active {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grabbing;
}

/* brush handles  */
#metric-modal .metric-chart .resize .handle {
    fill: #555;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .resize .handle-mini {
    fill: white;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke: #555;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .scale_button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .scale_button rect {
    fill: #eaeaea;
}
#metric-modal .metric-chart .scale_button:hover text {
    fill: #417DD6;
    transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart text#displayDates  {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* circle style */
#metric-modal .metric-chart .dot {
    fill: white;
    stroke: #00AA8D; /* default, changed in each theme */
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
    cursor: default;
    transition: stroke-width 0.06s ease-in;
    transition: stroke 0.06s ease-in;
}

#metric-modal .metric-chart .dot:hover {
    stroke: #00997e;
    stroke-width: 6px;
    transition: stroke-width 0.06s ease-out;
    transition: stroke 0.06s ease-out;
}

div.tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background: white;
    color: #565656;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

}

</style>
<body>
<div id="metric-modal"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

// example data
var metricName   = "views";
var metricCount  = [1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4];
var metricMonths = ["2018-06", "2013-04", "2015-11", "2012-10", "2014-09", "2014-02", "2016-02", "2016-04", "2016-06", "2014-12", "2013-07", "2017-01", "2015-10", "2012-12", "2013-05", "2018-04", "2015-06", "2017-03", "2014-08",
                    "2017-07", "2013-02", "2012-07", "2016-03", "2017-06", "2018-07", "2014-10", "2013-01", "2013-10", "2017-11", "2014-05", "2012-11", "2015-01", "2018-03", "2015-12", "2015-08", "2016-08", "2014-11", "2014-01",
                    "2013-06", "2012-08", "2015-09", "2016-07", "2013-03", "2012-09", "2016-05"];
var optwidth        = 600;
var optheight       = 370;


/*
* ========================================================================
*  Prepare data
* ========================================================================
*/


// to find missing data: get a sequence of all months between the min and max dates in the data.

// change dates to milliseconds
metricMonths.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
  theArray[index] = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse(part).getTime();
});

// get a list of all months in the range of data
var monthArray = d3.time.scale()
                .domain(d3.extent(metricMonths))
                .ticks(d3.time.months, 1);

// check if there is data for each month in monthArray, if so append count, otherwise append null
var dataset = [];
for(var i=0; i<monthArray.length; i++){

    var n = metricMonths.indexOf(monthArray[i].getTime());
    if (n>-1) {
        var count = metricCount[n];
    } else {
        var count = null;
    }
    dataset.push({count: count, month: monthArray[i]});
}

// a dataset without the null values is also needed to draw the missing data lines/areas
var dataset_no_null = dataset.filter(function(d) { return d.count !== null; });

/*
* ========================================================================
*  sizing
* ========================================================================
*/

/* === Focus chart === */

var margin  = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 20},
    width   = optwidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height  = optheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

/* === Context chart === */

var margin_context = {top: 320, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    height_context = optheight - margin_context.top - margin_context.bottom;

/*
* ========================================================================
*  x and y coordinates
* ========================================================================
*/

// the date range of available data:
var dataXrange = d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.month; });
var dataYrange = [0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.count; })];

// maximum date range allowed to display
var mindate = dataXrange[0],  // use the range of the data
    maxdate = dataXrange[1];

var DateFormat    =  d3.time.format("%b %Y");

var dynamicDateFormat = timeFormat([
    [d3.time.format("%Y"), function() { return true; }],// <-- how to display when Jan 1 YYYY
    [d3.time.format("%b %Y"), function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
    [function(){return "";}, function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }]
]);

/* === Focus Chart === */

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, (width)])
    .domain(dataXrange);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(dataYrange);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
        .tickSize(-(height))
    .ticks(customTickFunction)
    .tickFormat(dynamicDateFormat);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(4)
    .tickSize(-(width))
    .orient("right");

/* === Context Chart === */

var x2 = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([mindate, maxdate]);

var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height_context, 0])
    .domain(y.domain());

var xAxis_context = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x2)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(customTickFunction)
    .tickFormat(dynamicDateFormat);

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Plotted line and area variables
* ========================================================================
*/

/* === Focus Chart === */

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.count !== null; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .defined(line.defined())
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y0((height))
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

var line_missing = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

var area_missing = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y0((height))
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });


/* === Context Chart === */

var line_context = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.count !== null; })
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

var area_context = d3.svg.area()
    .defined(line_context.defined())
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y0((height_context))
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

var line_context_missing = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

var area_context_missing = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.month); })
    .y0((height_context))
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.count); });

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Variables for brushing and zooming behaviour
* ========================================================================
*/

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed)
    .on("brushend", brushend);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", draw)
    .on("zoomend", brushend);

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Define the SVG area ("vis") and append all the layers
* ========================================================================
*/

// === the main components === //

var vis = d3.select("#metric-modal").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "metric-chart");// CB -- "line-chart" -- CB //

vis.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    // clipPath is used to keep line and area from moving outside of plot area when user zooms/scrolls/brushes

var rect = vis.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "pane")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = vis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_context.left + "," + margin_context.top + ")");

var focus = vis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

rect.call(zoom)
    .call(draw);

// === current date range text & zoom buttons === //

var display_range_group = vis.append("g")
    .attr("id", "buttons_group")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ","+ 0 +")");

var expl_text = display_range_group.append("text")
    .text("Showing data from: ")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ","+ 10 +")");

display_range_group.append("text")
    .attr("id", "displayDates")
    .text(DateFormat(dataXrange[0]) + " - " + DateFormat(dataXrange[1]))
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 82 + ","+ 10 +")");

var expl_text = display_range_group.append("text")
    .text("Zoom to: ")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 180 + ","+ 10 +")");

// === the zooming/scaling buttons === //

var button_width = 40;
var button_height = 14;

// don't show year button if < 1 year of data
var dateRange  = dataXrange[1] - dataXrange[0],
    ms_in_year = 31540000000;

if (dateRange < ms_in_year)   {
    var button_data =["month","data"];
} else {
    var button_data =["year","month","data"];
};

var button = display_range_group.selectAll("g")
    .data(button_data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "scale_button")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (220 + i*button_width + i*10) + ",0)"; })
    .on("click", scaleDate);

button.append("rect")
    .attr("width", button_width)
    .attr("height", button_height)
    .attr("rx", 1)
    .attr("ry", 1);

button.append("text")
    .attr("dy", (button_height/2 + 3))
    .attr("dx", button_width/2)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

/* === focus chart === */

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width) + ", 0)");

// missing data area
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "area_missing")
    .attr("d", area_missing)
    .call(zoom)
    .call(draw);

// complete data area
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .call(zoom)
    .call(draw);

// x-axis
focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// missing data line
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "line_missing")
    .attr("d", line_missing);

// complete data line
focus.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

// circles
focus.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset_no_null)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {show_tooltip(d)} )
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {hide_tooltip(d)} );

/* === tooltip === */
var div = d3.select("#metric-modal").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

/* === context chart === */

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "area_missing")
    .attr("d", area_context_missing);

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area_context);

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset_no_null)
    .attr("class", "line_missing")
    .attr("d", line_context_missing);

context.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line_context);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height_context + ")")
    .call(xAxis_context);

/* === brush (part of context chart)  === */

var brushg = context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush);

brushg.selectAll(".extent")
   .attr("y", -6)
   .attr("height", height_context + 8);
   // .extent is the actual window/rectangle showing what's in focus

brushg.selectAll(".resize")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," +  -3 + ")")
    .attr('rx', 2)
    .attr('ry', 2)
    .attr("height", height_context + 6)
    .attr("width", 3);

brushg.selectAll(".resize")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "handle-mini")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-2,8)")
    .attr('rx', 3)
    .attr('ry', 3)
    .attr("height", (height_context/2))
    .attr("width", 7);
    // .resize are the handles on either size
    // of the 'window' (each is made of a set of rectangles)

/* === y axis title === */

vis.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y axis title")
    .text("Monthly " + this.metricName)
    .attr("x", (-(height/2)))
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

// allows zooming before any brush action
zoom.x(x);

/*
* ========================================================================
*  Functions
* ========================================================================
*/

// === tick/date formatting functions ===
// from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010864/d3-axis-labels-become-too-fine-grained-when-zoomed-in

function timeFormat(formats) {
  return function(date) {
    var i = formats.length - 1, f = formats[i];
    while (!f[1](date)) f = formats[--i];
    return f[0](date);
  };
};

function customTickFunction(t0, t1, dt)  {
    var labelSize = 42; //
    var maxTotalLabels = Math.floor(width / labelSize);

    function step(date, offset)
    {
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + offset);
    }

    var time = d3.time.month.ceil(t0), times = [], monthFactors = [1,3,4,12];

    while (time < t1) times.push(new Date(+time)), step(time, 1);
    var timesCopy = times;
    var i;
    for(i=0 ; times.length > maxTotalLabels ; i++)
        times = _.filter(timesCopy, function(d){
            return (d.getMonth()) % monthFactors[i] == 0;
        });

    return times;
};

// === tooltip functions === //

// from: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369
function show_tooltip(d) {

    if (d.count == 1) {
        var metricName_point = metricName.slice(0, -1);
    } else {
        var metricName_point = metricName;
    }

    div.transition()
        .duration(60)
        .style("opacity", 0.98);
    div.html("<b>" + DateFormat(d.month) + "</b><br/>"  + d.count + " " + metricName_point)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX -30) + "px")//(d3.event.pageX) + "px"
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY -40) + "px");//(d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"
    };

function hide_tooltip(d) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(60)
                .style("opacity", 0);
};


// === brush and zoom functions ===

function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    common_behaviour();
    // Reset zoom scale's domain
    zoom.x(x);
    updateDisplayDates();
    setYdomain();

}

function draw() {
    setYdomain();
    common_behaviour();
    // Force changing brush range
    brush.extent(x.domain());
    vis.select(".brush").call(brush);
    // and update the text showing range of dates.
    updateDisplayDates();
}

function common_behaviour() {
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
    focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
    focus.select(".area_missing").attr("d", area_missing);
    focus.select(".line_missing").attr("d", line_missing);
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    focus.selectAll(".dot")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); });
};

function brushend() {
// when brush stops moving:

    // check whether chart was scrolled out of bounds and fix,
    var b = brush.extent();
    var out_of_bounds = brush.extent().some(function(e) { return e < mindate | e > maxdate; });
    if (out_of_bounds){ b = moveInBounds(b) };

};

function updateDisplayDates() {

    var b = brush.extent();
    // update the text that shows the range of displayed dates
    var localBrushDateStart = (brush.empty()) ? DateFormat(dataXrange[0]) : DateFormat(b[0]),
        localBrushDateEnd   = (brush.empty()) ? DateFormat(dataXrange[1]) : DateFormat(b[1]);

    // Update start and end dates in upper right-hand corner
    d3.select("#displayDates")
        .text(localBrushDateStart == localBrushDateEnd ? localBrushDateStart : localBrushDateStart + " - " + localBrushDateEnd);
};

function moveInBounds(b) {
// move back to boundaries if user pans outside min and max date.

    var ms_in_year = 31536000000,
        brush_start_new,
        brush_end_new;

    if       (b[0] < mindate)   { brush_start_new = mindate; }
    else if  (b[0] > maxdate)   { brush_start_new = new Date(maxdate.getTime() - ms_in_year); }
    else                        { brush_start_new = b[0]; };

    if       (b[1] > maxdate)   { brush_end_new = maxdate; }
    else if  (b[1] < mindate)   { brush_end_new = new Date(mindate.getTime() + ms_in_year); }
    else                        { brush_end_new = b[1]; };

    brush.extent([brush_start_new, brush_end_new]);

    brush(d3.select(".brush").transition());
    brushed();
    draw();

    return(brush.extent())
};

function setYdomain(){
// this function dynamically changes the y-axis to fit the data in focus

    // get the min and max date in focus
    var xleft = new Date(x.domain()[0]);
    var xright = new Date(x.domain()[1]);

    // a function that finds the nearest point to the right of a point
    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.month; }).right;

    // get the y value of the line at the left edge of view port:
    var iL = bisectDate(dataset_no_null, xleft);

    if (dataset_no_null[iL] !== undefined && dataset_no_null[iL-1] !== undefined) {

        var left_dateBefore = dataset_no_null[iL-1].month,
            left_dateAfter = dataset_no_null[iL].month;

        var intfun = d3.interpolateNumber(dataset_no_null[iL-1].count, dataset_no_null[iL].count);
        var yleft = intfun((xleft-left_dateBefore)/(left_dateAfter-left_dateBefore));
    } else {
        var yleft = 0;
    }

    // get the x value of the line at the right edge of view port:
    var iR = bisectDate(dataset_no_null, xright);

    if (dataset_no_null[iR] !== undefined && dataset_no_null[iR-1] !== undefined) {

        var right_dateBefore = dataset_no_null[iR-1].month,
            right_dateAfter = dataset_no_null[iR].month;

        var intfun = d3.interpolateNumber(dataset_no_null[iR-1].count, dataset_no_null[iR].count);
        var yright = intfun((xright-right_dateBefore)/(right_dateAfter-right_dateBefore));
    } else {
        var yright = 0;
    }

    // get the y values of all the actual data points that are in view
    var dataSubset = dataset.filter(function(d){ return d.month >= xleft && d.month <= xright; });
    var countSubset = [];
    dataSubset.map(function(d) {countSubset.push(d.count);});

    // add the edge values of the line to the array of counts in view, get the max y;
    countSubset.push(yleft);
    countSubset.push(yright);
    var ymax_new = d3.max(countSubset);

    if(ymax_new == 0){
        ymax_new = dataYrange[1];
    }

    // reset and redraw the yaxis
    y.domain([0, ymax_new*1.05]);
    focus.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

};

function scaleDate(d,i) {
// action for buttons that scale focus to certain time interval

    var b = brush.extent(),
        interval_ms,
        brush_end_new,
        brush_start_new;

    if      (d == "year")   { interval_ms = 31536000000}
    else if (d == "month")  { interval_ms = 2592000000 };

    if ( d == "year" | d == "month" )  {

        if((maxdate.getTime() - b[1].getTime()) < interval_ms){
        // if brush is too far to the right that increasing the right-hand brush boundary would make the chart go out of bounds....
            brush_start_new = new Date(maxdate.getTime() - interval_ms); // ...then decrease the left-hand brush boundary...
            brush_end_new = maxdate; //...and set the right-hand brush boundary to the maxiumum limit.
        } else {
        // otherwise, increase the right-hand brush boundary.
            brush_start_new = b[0];
            brush_end_new = new Date(b[0].getTime() + interval_ms);
        };

    } else if ( d == "data")  {
        brush_start_new = dataXrange[0];
        brush_end_new = dataXrange[1]
    } else {
        brush_start_new = b[0];
        brush_end_new = b[1];
    };

    brush.extent([brush_start_new, brush_end_new]);

    // now draw the brush to match our extent
    brush(d3.select(".brush").transition());
    // now fire the brushstart, brushmove, and brushend events
    brush.event(d3.select(".brush").transition());
};

const selectLine = vis.append('line').attr('y1', 20).attr('y2', height + 20).style('stroke', 'blue');
vis.on('mousemove', () => selectLine.attr('x1', d3.event.layerX).attr('x2', d3.event.layerX));

</script>
</body>
```